# Returning an Image only Once Loaded

Tags: javascript, image

I want to return an image from a JavaScript function, but only once said image is loaded. I've been running into problems by returning not loaded images from this function

```
function modifyImage(src) {

//do some stuff to src

let dest = new Image()
dest.src = "modified code, whatever"

return dest
}
```

By the time the function returns dest, dest is not yet loaded. How can I wait for dest to load?

Comment: I think 'onload' event solve your problem take look at  https://idiallo.com/javascript/img-detect-loaded

Answer (score 1):

You want the `load` event.

Note: This is async. That means the file will load AFTER the function has finished, and you will have to use the call back.

```js
function modifyImage(src) {

  //do some stuff to src

  let dest = new Image()
  dest.addEventListener("load", () => {
    console.log("Loaded");
  });

  dest.src = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"

  return dest
}

modifyImage();
```

Comment: Lol, you have answered twice with the exact same content, only that one is formatted with indents

Comment: @Cypherjac Actually got reposted when I edited the comment to fix formatting.  Thanks.

Comment: The thing is, I'm creating these images in a `for` loop. (More specifically, I'm iterating over an array) So, I need to create (and fully load) an image **before proceeding to the next element in the `for` loop.** Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: By not using a loop!  Use the same code I have, create a index that you pass to modifyImage.  Use that index to find the URL in the array.  In the callback, call modifyImage again,  with the value of `index+1` -- until you reach the end of the array.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher So you're saying use recursion? Won't that eat up resources/isn't that bad practice?

Comment: There is a debate about if this is actually recursion or not for technical reasons that I'll put aside -- but the answer, either way, is no. Firstly, because this uses async callbacks, it doesn't use the stackspace that normal recursion uses and secondly -- even if it did -- nothing wrong with that.  Those resources would be freed when the stack unwinds.